# Bootstrap input-group-addon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem using the class `input-group-addon`: my html code is generated by JavaScript and I generate it in identical structures in my various pages.

But, in one page, it works, and in another page, it doesn't work. I can't figure out why!

When it's working:

[image]

And when it's not:

[image]

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon input-sm">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </div>
    <input id="kwtab_fieldfilter" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" placeholder="Filter">
  </div>
</div>
```

Do you have an idea why is it not working?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: its working fine for me.. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/9769/

Comment: Did you change the `display` property of any of these classes `.input-group .form-control, .input-group-addon, .input-group-btn` somewhere in your CSS ? Maybe in combination with `input-sm`, something like `.input-group-addon.input-sm {
  display: block;
}` ?

Comment: Can you give me a second to write an answer to this question because there is something else i have noticed in your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we can't see your additional styling it is pretty hard to tell where the problem might be, but there are at least two thing in your 'html' that might cause problems.

**First**

You have added the `input-sm` class onto the `div` with the `input-group-addon`. The `input-sm` class should be placed onto the `div` with the `input-group` class as the **Bootstrap** docs state:

> [**Sizing**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-sizing)
>
> Add the relative form sizing classes to the .input-group itself and contents within will automatically resize—no need for repeating the form control size classes on each element.

**Second**

The `div` element by default has a `display` property of `block`, unless you change this to something else, whereas the `input-group-addon`and several other **Bootstrap** `form` and `input` classes have a `display` property of `table-cell`. The only way i could reproduce your strange formatting of your `input-group` was by changing the `display` property to `block` on some of the relevant classes.

Here is an example:

```css
.input-group-addon.input-sm {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon input-sm">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </div>
    <input id="kwtab_fieldfilter" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" placeholder="Filter" />
  </div>
</div>
```

So, to make a long story short you might want to construct your `html` like this:

```css
/*****************************************
  Do not change the display property
  of any of these classes to block.

  .input-group
  .form-control
  .input-group-addon
  .input-group-btn

  the default display value of these
  classes is table-cell.
******************************************/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group input-sm">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </span>
    <input id="kwtab_fieldfilter" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" placeholder="Filter" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me :)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon input-sm">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </div>
    <input id="kwtab_fieldfilter" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" placeholder="Filter">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, and it should be working everytime but in one of my pages, it doesn't. :(

Comment: Perhaps form-group div(div with class name form-group)'s  parent class has fixed width

Comment: I looked at it and there is no problem with that.